# Accessing JSon raw tokens in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, json

My json string looks like { abc: 123, def: 442, ghi=444 } - say stock list.

I dont know what quotes are coming in , i.e I dont know what is abc, def etc is. I need to get this token dynamically. Any pointers would be of great help !

BTW, this has to run in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JsonObject,JsonPrimitive, and JsonArray classes.  The static Load method can be used to load the result string into an object that can then be accessed with [] accessors.